# UserForm TextBox Font change (Italic back to Default)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text that shows on a textbox that appears when the forms starts and disappears when the user enters the textbox to enter some... text. Well, the problem is that i have it set to Italic but when i turn it off (False), it does not change. Here is the code:

```
Private Userform_Initialize

    'Text in italic: "Legajo"
    If TextBox5.Text = "" Then
    TextBox5.Font.Italic = True
    TextBox5.ForeColor = cDimColor
    TextBox5.Text = "Legajo"
    End If

Private Sub TextBox5_Enter()

Dim cStdColor As Long
cStdColor = &H80000008

 If TextBox5 = "Legajo" Then

 TextBox5.Font.Italic = False 'Does not Work
 TextBox5.ForeColor = cStdColor
 TextBox5 = ""

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Its always on Times New Roman. I tried setting it on bold for example, but it does keep the italic...

Comment: Where has the `Inside` come from?

Comment: I corrected it, it was just to refer that it was "Inside" that statement

Comment: Consider naming your controls. `FilenameBox` is infinitely clearer than `TextBox5`. That said the `Enter` event is fired whenever the control is *entered*, meaning, when the control gets focus - not at every keypress.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same situation. This worked for me:

```
userform1.textbox1.FontBold = False
```

same for Italic and Underline:

```
FontItalic = False
FontUnderline = False
```

Nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use Keyup event.

```
Private Sub TextBox5_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim cStdColor As Long
    cStdColor = &H80000008

    If TextBox5 = "Legajo" Then

        TextBox5.Font.Italic = False 'Does not Work
    Else
        TextBox5.Font.Italic = True
    End If
     TextBox5.ForeColor = cStdColor
End Sub
```